# ¿Cómo anonimizar cadenas de un data.frame?

Tags: r

Necesito compartir un `data.frame` con un colega, pero quisiera "anonimizar" de alguna manera los datos. La idea sería:

- Nada demasiado avanzado (no necesito respetar ningún estándar o norma)
- No reversible
- Solo para las cadenas
- Simple y rápido

Supongamos unos datos como estos:

```
df <- data.frame(nombre = c('Juan', 'Pedro'),
                 Edad = c(34, 45),
                 dni = c('12345678', '87654321'))
```

La idea sería aplicar el algoritmo solo sobre el nombre y el dni.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurren algunas alternativas:

#### 1. Transformar las cadenas en un factor para luego usar el índice de cada `level`

```
anonymize_str_vector <- function(x) {
  if( !is.character(x) ) stop('x is not a vector of characters')
  as.character(as.numeric(factor(x)))
}

anonymize_str_df <- function(df) {
  if( !is.data.frame(df) ) stop('df is not a data.frame')
  convert <- sapply(df, is.character)
  df[,convert] <- sapply(df[,convert], anonymize_str_vector)
  df
}

anonymize_str_df(df)

  nombre Edad dni
1      1   34   1
2      2   45   2
```

#### 2. Generar caracteres al azar del tamaño de cada cadena

```
anonymize_str_vector <- function(x) {
  if( !is.character(x) ) stop('x is not a vector of characters')
  
  anonymize_scalar <- function(s) {
    suppressWarnings(if (!is.na(as.numeric(s))) {sample_data <- 0:9} else {sample_data <- letters})
    paste0(sample(sample_data, nchar(s), replace = TRUE), collapse="")
  }
  sapply(x, anonymize_scalar)
}

anonymize_str_df(df)

  nombre Edad      dni
1   wgon   34 36360598
2  cbval   45 18800229
```

Aclaración: técnicamente hablando esta forma sería reversible si se conoce la "semilla" con que se inició el proceso.

#### 3. Usar alguna rutina de "hashing"

Fuente: [Data anonymization in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/11/data-anonymization-in-r/)

```
library(digest)

anonymize_str_vector <- function(x, algo="crc32") {
  if( !is.character(x) ) stop('x is not a vector of characters')
  unq_hashes <- vapply(unique(x), function(object) digest(object, algo=algo), FUN.VALUE="", USE.NAMES=TRUE)
  unname(unq_hashes[x])
}

anonymize_str_df(df)

    nombre Edad      dni
1 5c97bc37   34 2670dbda
2 e6473558   45 bc76be3a
```